# How do I convert a timestamp to seconds-since-midnight?

Tags: python, datetime, time, python-datetime

Suppose I have this timestamp:

```
In [146]: t
Out[146]: datetime.time(11, 2, 5, 110521)
```

How do I convert this to the the number of seconds since midnight? One approach is to first convert this to a `timedelta`:

```
In [147]: datetime.timedelta(hours=t.hour, minutes=t.minute, seconds=t.second, microseconds=t.microsecond)
Out[147]: datetime.timedelta(0, 39725, 110521)
```

Then I can take the `total_seconds()`. But this seems really long-winded. Is there a more Pythonic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just multiply the `hour` and `minute` attributes, divide the `microsecond` attribute and add it all together:

```
>>> (t.hour * 3600) + (t.minute * 60) + t.second + (t.microsecond / 1000000.0)
39725.110521
```

You cannot use `datetime.time.min` because `datetime.time` objects don't support subtraction, unfortunately.

You *could* produce a `datetime.datetime` object by combining the time plus `datetime.date.min` (earliest supported date), then subtract `datetime.datetime.min` (earliest supported date and time), but that's long-winded too:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.min, t) - datetime.datetime.min
datetime.timedelta(0, 39725, 110521)
>>> (datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.min, t) - datetime.datetime.min).total_seconds
39725.110521
```

Comment: Yeah, I had originally tried subtracting `datetime.time(0)`, but that's not supported.